# How can we click on a parent element of a particular text in protractor

Tags: protractor

Our UI code is given below.

```
<div _ngcontent-wuu-c29="" class="frx-rule-block ng-star-inserted">
   <div _ngcontent-wuu-c29="" class="frx-rule-header">
      <h4 _ngcontent-wuu-c29="">1</h4>
      <i _ngcontent-wuu-c29="" class="demo-icon"></i>
      <label _ngcontent-wuu-c29="" class="frx-rule-title">Rule Group</label>
   </div>
   <div _ngcontent-wuu-c29="" class="frx-rule-body">
      <div _ngcontent-wuu-c29="" class="frx-rule-descr">
          <h3 _ngcontent-wuu-c29="">Sample rule groups</h3>
          <p _ngcontent-wuu-c29="">Sample description.</p>
      </div>
      <div>--------</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

We have a main div and inside of this main div we have many child class elements "frx-rule-block ng-star-inserted" as given above.The text "Sample rule groups" in the h3 tag is different in different ".frx-rule-block ng-star-inserted".I need to click on the digit 1 in the h4 tag for this particular h3 tag(this digit is changing every time, so i cannot specify which is the text inside of h4 tag).So how can i select this particular text "Sample rule groups" and click on the h4 tag.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer

```
let h4ByText = (text) => element(by.xpath(`//*[@class="frx-rule-body"]//h3[contains(text(),"${text}")]//ancestor::div[contains(@class,"frx-rule-block")]//h4`));
```

If you can't understand how it works, lmk I'll give you full answer

Comment: Great Thanks...its working...I have used           
let h4ByText = element(by.xpath(`//*[@class="frx-rule-body"]//h3[contains(text(),"Sample rule groups")]//ancestor::div[contains(@class,"frx-rule-block")]//h4`));
return browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", h4ByText.getWebElement());

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to select a sibling element by xpath but I don't remember it. So here is a workaround for you:

`let myElement = element(by.cssContainingTex(".frx-rule-title", "Rule Group").element(by.xpath("..")).element(by.xpath("//h4[contains(text(), '1')]"))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using xpath at all so here's how I would go about doing it. It's definitely more code and work to do it this way but I avoid xpath at all costs. Just a personal preference.

```
const match = 'Sample rule groups';

// get all blocks 
const ruleblocks = element.all(by.css('.frx-rule-block'));

// find the one that contains the header you want
const relevantBlock = await ruleblocks.filter(block => {
  const ruleBodyHeader = block.$('.frx-rule-body > h3');

  return ruleBodyHeader.getText().then(text => {
    return text === match;
  }
}).first();

const ruleHeader = relevantBlock.$('.frx-rule-header > h4');
await ruleHeader.click();
```